# Incompatible types: 'T' and 'TObject'

Tags: delphi

In `TMyList<T>`, a generic list similar to `TList<T>` but simpler, I am trying to free any objects that may be stored in it if `OwnsObjects` is true.

I can check if the item is `tkClass` by using `GetTypeKind(T)`, but that does not get me anywhere because I can't seem to be able to typecast `T` to `TObject` to free it.

```pascal
procedure TMyList<T>.Clear;
var
  Index1: Integer;
begin
  if FOwnsObjects then begin
    Index1 := 0;
    while Index1 < FCount do begin
      case GetTypeKind(FList^[Index1]) of
        tkClass: begin
            if TObject(FList^[Index1]) <> nil then begin
              TObject(FList^[Index1]).Free;
              TObject(FList^[Index1]) := nil;
            end;
          end;
      end;
      Inc(Index1);
    end;
  end;
  {more code..}
end;
```

Is there no way to do this?

Comment: You can also use [`TObjectList<T>`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList)

Comment: Thank you, Remy.

2 short follow up questuins, if I may:

Would this be the correct use
 FList^[Index1] := Default(T);
for
 FList^[Index1] := nil;

The other question is:

How do I rewrite this line?

if FList^[Index1] = nil then Delete(Index1);

It isn't accepting FList^[Index1] = Default(T)

Comment: Thank you Dalija. But in my use case a generic TMyList will be more useful. Plus, I want to have my own implementation without the bloat taht come TList<T> and derivatives.